# Bash - Strings, Commands and Escaping (oh, my!)

Tags: bash, shell

I'm wasting so much time right now trying to figure out something so simple....

pseudo code (mixture of several syntax's, sorry):

```
cmd1 = "find /my/starting/path -type f | grep -v -f /my/exclude/files"
cmd2 = " nl -ba -s'  ' "
cmd3 = " | xargs mv -t /move/here/dir " 

echo run_command_and_return_output($cmd1$cmd2)

$cmd1$cmd3  # just this now... 

# i don't actually want a function... but the name explains what i want to do
function run_command_and_return_output(){ /* magic */ }
```

---

this works....

```
FIND=$(find $LOG_DIR -type f | grep -v -f $EXCLUDE | nl -ba -s'   ')

printf "%s\n" "$FIND"
```

this does not...

```
NL="nl -ba -s'  '"
FIND=$(find $LOG_DIR -type f -mtime +$ARCH_AGE | grep -v -f $EXCLUDE | $NL)

printf "%s\n" "$FIND"
```

and neither does this...

```
NL='nl -ba -s'\''   '\'' '
```

this definitely does work, though:

```
find /my/starting/path -type f | grep -v -f /my/exclude/files |  nl -ba -s'  '
```

or

```
FIND=$(find $LOG_DIR -type f -mtime +$ARCH_AGE | grep -v -f $EXCLUDE | nl -ba -s'  ' )
```

Comment: BashFAQ #50 covers this topic rather comprehensively: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: omg... i think i'm gonna figure it out.  right as i posted the question.  this always happens.  always.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `eval`.

Comment: By the way -- by convention, all-uppercase names are reserved for environment variables and shell builtins. To avoid overwriting these by mistake, shell variables not exported to the environment should have at least one lowercase character in their names (and all-lowercase names are common).

Comment: i'm just trying to modify someone's code.... it needs logging.  and they have like 10 functions were there could be 2...  all his vars were uppercase.  i thought it was a thing...?

Comment: All-uppercase variable names are common in code written by folks who've seen environment variables and builtins used and assume that's how all variables are supposed to work in shell. Sadly, learning shell is often by example, and examples are often awful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short form: Expanding `$foo` unquoted runs the content through string-splitting and glob expansion, but **not** syntactical parsing. This means that characters which would do quoting and escaping in a different context aren't honored as syntax, but are only treated as data.

If you want to run a string through syntactical parsing, use `eval` -- but mind the caveats, which are large and security-impacting.

Much better is to use the right tools for the job -- building individual simple commands (not pipelines!) in shell arrays, and using functions as the composable unit for constructing complex commands. [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describes these tools -- and goes into in-depth discussion on which of them is appropriate when.

---

To get a bit more concrete:

```
nl=( nl -ba -s'  ' )
find_output=$(find "$log_dir" -type f -mtime "+$arch_age" | grep -v -f "$exclude" | "${nl[@]}")
printf "%s\n" "$find_output"
```

...would be correct, since it tracks the simple command `nl` as an array.

Comment: "but mind the caveats, which are large and **potentially security-impacting**"  This cannot be stressed enough.  Even glob expansion can be dangerous.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, ...indeed. I've seen glob expansion result in multiple TB of backups being unexpectedly deleted after a buffer overflow dumped garbage (including a whitespace-surrounded wildcard) into a filename in a directory that was otherwise considered certain to only have names matching `[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Comment: ...incidentally, since the only program which had been writing into that directory prior to a new software stack's introduction (the latter being the trigger of said bug) was written in Java, such buffer overflows were also considered impossible when the backup maintenance system was designed. Ahh, the perils of designing only for the code you need to interoperate with today, rather than trying to cover all corner cases...

Comment: eval has definitely worked since the beginning of this for me... is there any alternative, though?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin, ...of course there is. Have you read the FAQ yet? I also edited in an example of using an array for the `nl` simple command.

Comment: ok.  so... real quick (no, i only read to #2 and ADD kicked in so i went back to brute force on the codez) -- *why* did you turn `nl` into an array?  (aka why might i want to do that to things in the future?)

Comment: @gloomy.penguin, ...because in the assignment `array=( values )`, `values` go through syntax parsing before being assigned (and are stored with the element boundaries unambiguously delimited) -- whereas a string variable **never** goes through syntax parsing unless you use `eval`, hence the bug that brought you here.

Comment: Here's a fun read on wildcard expansion and its pitfalls: https://dicesoft.net/projects/wildcard-code-execution-exploit.htm

Comment: so... after a week of scope creep... [this](http://pastebin.com/3SuFCMpu) is what I've ended up with.  still have some testing to go.  if you would happen to give that a click and notice any glaring issues, feel free let me know....... and thanks again for the help a week ago.

Comment: There are a lot of stylistic quibbles, but the only real correctness-impacting thing I've seen so far is building an array with `find_results=( $(find ...) )`. Don't do that -- it doesn't handle filenames with spaces or wildcards in their names (or, especially, wildcards surrounded by spaces) correctly. Actually, using newline-delimited lists of filenames is hazardous in general (since filenames can contain newlines!), and you do that in several other places too.

Comment: Oh -- also, don't ever use variables in the first argument to `printf`. `printf 'rmdir %q\n' "$dir"`, not `printf $dir\n` -- using `%q` also gives you the advantage of escaping wildcards, whitespace, etc. to provide a command that will Do The Right Thing when parsed by a shell.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string for a discussion of _why_ the first argument to `printf` should always be a constant -- though it's a bigger problem in C than in shell.

Comment: niiiiiice.  thank you for looking.  i will fix all that.  this is my first go with all this.  before two months ago, i could get around on the command line and sort of use vi/vim but that's about it.  i've certainly never touched any shell script before this last week.  i've had to google *a lot.*