# Bash shell scripting rsync with variables

Tags: bash, ubuntu, rsync

I have the following for-loop which loops through all the given sources that need to be copied.

```
for i in "${sources[@]}"; do
    exclude="--exclude 'exclude_folder/exclude_file'"

    rsync -az $exclude $i $destination
done
```

However, the exclude option is not working.

```
for i in "${sources[@]}"; do
    exclude="--exclude 'exclude_folder/exclude_file'"

    rsync -az "$exclude" "$i" "$destination"
done
```

If I use the code above, rsync will exit and give an error that it is an unknown option.

If I simply use the following code, it works, but I want to use a variable for the exclude option.

```
for i in "${sources[@]}"; do
    rsync -az --exclude 'exclude_folder/exclude_file' $i $destination
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `eval`.

Your code:

```
for i in "${sources[@]}"; do
    exclude="--exclude 'exclude_folder/exclude_file'"

    rsync -az "$exclude" "$i" "$destination"
done
```

would be then (I'm trying to be as close to your logic as possible):

```
for i in "${sources[@]}"; do
    exclude="--exclude 'exclude_folder/exclude_file'"
    rsync_command="rsync -az $exclude $i $destination"

    eval rsync_command
done
```

From the `eval` man pages:

> eval
>
> Evaluate several commands/arguments
>
> Syntax
>         eval [arguments]
>
> The arguments are concatenated together into a single command, which
>   is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the exit
>   status of eval. If there are no arguments or only empty arguments, the
>   return status is zero.
>
> eval is a POSIX `special' builtin

**EDIT**

Gordon Davisson is right about the bugs/insecurities in `eval`.  If any other solution is available then it is better to use it.  Here the bash arrays are better.  The array answer is superior answer.

Please see the answer at **[Bash: need help passing a a variable to rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710476/bash-need-help-passing-a-a-variable-to-rsync)**

Comment: Please to **not** use `eval` -- it has a well-deserved reputation as a source of obscure and incomprehensible bugs. Arrays are a much better way to handle this; see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: @GordonDavisson you are right about the bugs (insecurities).  I'll link the proposed duplicate.

Comment: It's not just insecurities (i.e. vulnerability to *intentional* attacks); in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554819/bash-strings-commands-and-escaping-oh-my/26554864#comment41731531_26554864),  Charles Duffy says he's "seen glob expansion result in multiple TB of backups being unexpectedly deleted after a buffer overflow dumped garbage (including a whitespace-surrounded wildcard) into a filename in a directory that was otherwise considered certain to only have names matching `[A-Za-z0-9]+`". Shouldn't be a risk here (`--delete-excluded` is not supplied), but still...

Answer (score 0):

Example list directories to exclude (also wildcharts) :

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
LIST="rootfs usr data data2"
for d in $LIST; do
rsync -az --exclude /$d/ .....
done
```